# Is there a way to disconnect a SharePoint calendar connected to Outlook with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, outlook, calendar, pst

We have SharePoint calendars connected to Microsoft Outlook.  When connected, Outlook creates a SharePoint List.pst file in %UserProfile%\Documents\Outlook folder.  We need to programmatically move these SharePoint List.pst files outside of the Documents folder.  However, when we move the SharePoint List.pst to another directory and Outlook is opened we get an error message saying: "**The file C:\Users\UserProfile\Documents\Outlook\SharePoint Lists.pst cannot be found.**"

Is there a way to remove the Calendar pst mapping in Outlook similar to how an Email personal store (pst) is removed in powershell?

Any assistance is appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHfYP.jpg)

Comment: What is the purpose of moving them? They really don't have much data in them.

Comment: We are in the process of implementing OneDrive for Business with folder redirection.  OneDrive does not support syncing any [PST files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-remove-an-outlook-pst-data-file-from-onedrive-b6b9e522-59bd-40f7-949f-168d0aa9b38e).  Thus we must move these PST files outside of the Documents folder.